# Get browser to show error when javascript fails

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm new to JavaScript development. There's one problem I find annoying in particular, and I'm hoping there's a solution to it I haven't found yet.

The problem concerns feedback/debugability when JavaScript execution fails. Whenever 'normal' languages would throw an exeption, the JavaScript execution just stops without any message.

For example, I have this code:

```
var Something = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.oneMethod = function () { /*whatever*/ };
  self.otherMethod = function() { /*whatever*/ };
}

var instance = new Something();
instance.oneMethod(); // fine
instance.wrongMethodCall(); // does not exist!
```

I would expect that last line to give an error, somehow, somewhere. But no, my browser console remains empty. Can I change something (either in the code or in my browser, Chrome) so that this will give an error, preferably with the line it occurred on (such as a `throw` statement would)?

Comment: And if you use Mozilla Firefox does the console show errors ?

Comment: Throws an error just fine for me in Chrome. `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Chrome and Firefox do definitely display an error on the console if the console was already open when the error ocurred. Are you sure that the code is even executed? Did you try an alert or a breakpoint close to the error?

Comment: Are you sure that the JS tab (or the All tab) is selected so you're actually seeing JS errors appear in the Chrome console?

Comment: Are you sure that JS is enabled?  (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BYOQskiuGU0)

Comment: @PeterVC Yes, simple console.log statements do show up.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that do not have filters set for your Developer Tools
[image]

Comment: Yup, that window looks exactly the same for me :(

Answer (score -2):

### Use console.log

Apply `console.log('text here')` in and around new functions during development to better track the code's progression. You should do something like the following:

```
var Something = function() {
  console.log('Constructor for "Something" successfully called.');
  var self = this;
  self.oneMethod = function () { /*whatever*/ };
  self.otherMethod = function() { /*whatever*/ };
}

console.log('Attempting to create new object: Something . . .');
var instance = new Something();
console.log('Object created: ', instance);
console.log('Performing "oneMethod" method of object "Something" . . .');
instance.oneMethod(); // fine
console.log('Performing "wrongMethodCall" method of object "Something" . . .');
instance.wrongMethodCall(); // does not exist!
```

This will help you to identify where your code is breaking, why, and can also return enumerated objects to help you review the methods, properties, and prototypes of new constructs.

Comment: Yes, that would solve the problem, but it's a lot more work than simply having the browser tell me this.

Comment: As others have pointed out, your function may not be running at all. You need to see how far it is getting to be sure. But hey, by all means down-vote me for trying to help.